# Proof $(A\oplus B) \times C = C \times (A-B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(A\oplus B) \times C = C \times (A-B)$

For starters, $((A\cap B)^c\cap (A\cup B)) \times C  = C \times (A \cap B^c)$

I don't know how to continue from here since there's Cartesian product

Comment: What does $\oplus$ mean?

Comment: @Wuestenfux symmetrical difference

Answer (score 1):

It's false. Let $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$ and $C=\{3\}$ so that
$$
(A\oplus B)\times C= \{1,2\}\times\{3\} = \{(1,3),(2,3)\}
$$
while
$$
C\times (A-B) = \{3\}\times\{1\} = \{(3,1)\}.
$$